# generic Func with parameter

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, func

I have a lot of methods where I need to get data from an external API and manage errors the same way.

So I would like to avoid to have the same code in all the methods...

I tried to use Func and I have this code working for a method without parameter.

The method :

```
private async Task<T> ExecuteAction<T>(Func<Task<T>> action) where T : class
    {
        var securityException = false;
        object response = null;

        try
        {
            response = await action();
        }
        catch (MySecurityException)
        {
            securityException = true;
        }

        if (securityException)
        {
            // new login
            response = await action();
        }

        else if (// other condition)
        {
            //Do something
        }

        return (T) response;
    }
```

The method call :

```
Func<Task<string>> action = myApiClient.Action;

var test = await ExecuteAction<string>(action);
```

How can I do the same thing with parameters ? Something like :

```
Func<Task<string>> action = myApiClient.Action(parameter1, parameter2);
```

Is there an easy way to modify my method to add parameters ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a lambda expression:

```
Func<Task<string>> action = ()=> myApiClient.Action(parameter1, parameter2)
```

And pass it to the method you already have.